What is the natural frequency of the system?

The natural frequency equation is $\omega_n =\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ and
the general form of a spring and mass system is $x’’+\frac{k}{m}x=0$
For this particular system I found the natural frequency to be $\sqrt{\frac{k_1+k_2+k_3}{m}} $ but my questions are this: If $k_3$ is in series with $k_1$&$k_2$, why is it treated as though its in parallel with them and if $k_3$ opposes the motion of the other two springs, why would it be added to $k_1$& $k_2$ and not subtracted?

How does it change of $k_3$ is instead mounted between $k_1$ and $k_2$?
The potential energy goes as:
$$ U_3 = \frac 1 2 k_3 x^2 $$
and under the proposed transformation:
$$ U'_3 = \frac 1 2 k_3 (-x)^2 = \frac 1 2 k_2(+x)^2 = U_3 $$

Ahhh I see, they can be treated as parallel because $k_3$ is in between $k_1$ and $k_2$, regardless of which side of the mass it is on.

It's not that it's between them...the system is also invariant under permutations of $(1, 2, 3)$. It's that springs that are physically in parallel have their constants added arithmetically (aka: in series), and springs that are physically in series gave the spring constants added harmonically (aka: in parallel), just like capacitors. There terminology "added in series (parallel)" comes from resistors, where series -> arithmetic, parallel -> harmonic.

When I need to remember which is which, I think of nothing. What is the spring constant of nothing? It is zero. A lone spring is in parallel with an arbitrary number of $k=0$ springs, and I need to add them in series $k = k + 0 + 0 + \cdots$ checks out. Meanwhile nothing is equal to a resistor with $\infty\Omega$, and a single resistor is in parallel with nothing, so I add them harmonically: $1/R = 1/R + 1/\infty$. Works for capacitors too...havent thought about inductors, though, I just look that one up.
